# XML XSLT Stylesheet not loading

Tags: xml, xslt

Keep getting the following error:

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

Heres my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl href="computers.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE computers SYSTEM "computers.dtd">
<computers>
    <computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i7 3770k</cpu>
    <motherboard>MSI M-Power</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>1000</hdd>
        <ssd>128</ssd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="ATI">7950</gpu>
    <psu>750</psu>
</computer>
<computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="Yes">Intel i5 3570k</cpu>
    <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 4</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>1000</hdd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="ATI">7870</gpu>
    <psu>600</psu>
</computer>
<computer>
    <cpu ghz="3.5" unlocked="No">Intel i5 3550</cpu>
    <motherboard>ASRock Extreme 3</motherboard>
    <ram>8</ram>
    <storage>
        <hdd>500</hdd>
    </storage>
    <gpu group="GeForce">9600GT</gpu>
    <psu>500</psu>
</computer>
```

DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT computer (cpu,motherboard,ram,storage,gpu,psu) >
<!ELEMENT cpu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT motherboard (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ram (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT storage(hdd,ssd*)>
<!ELEMENT hdd (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ssd (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gpu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT psu (#PCDATA)>

<!ATLIST cpu
ghz CDATA #REQUIRED>
unlocked (Yes|No) "No">
<!ATLIST gpu
group (ATI|GeForce) "ATI">
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>HELLO WORLD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="computers/computer">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu/@ghz"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cpu/@unlocked"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="motherboard"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ram"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="storage"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="hdd"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ssd"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="gpu"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="psu"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please could someone help me figure whats wrong with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl href="computers.xsl"?>
```

should be

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="computers.xsl"?>
```